# Android: Detect currently active phone number during phone call

Tags: android, phone-number, phone-call

Goal: On the Android platform, detect the phone number of the individual with whom the user is speaking to now.

Currently, using PhoneListener, there exists a certain ambiguity in the case of calls on hold.

Case: User is talking to someone during a call ("Call 1"). The user is therefore in call state OFFHOOK. Then the user is in state RINGING indicating an incoming phone call ("Call 2"). The state then changes to OFFHOOK. This could indicate one of two possibilities -- either the user answered Call 2, and placed Call 1 on hold. Alternatively, the user rejected Call 2 and returned to Call 1.

How is it possible to distinguish between the two cases? Is it possible to detect the phone number of the CURRENT CALL on the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a PhoneStateLister and [onCallStateChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallStateChanged%28int,%20java.lang.String%29).
 There you can also see the incoming number.

Comment: There is a question of ambiguity - the only time that a phone number is received is in the RINGING state. This state does not imply who the user is speaking to at the moment, just that a call is incoming. Call 1 is phone number X. Call 2 comes in, I receive a RINGING state from phone number Y. The state now returns to OFFHOOK. Who am I talking to? Am I talking to Call 1, phone number X, or Call 2, phone number Y? That's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: but this method always has the rinining number as a parameter, also if the state is OFFHOOK. So I think the phone number in the OFFHOOK state is the phone number your currently talking to. But to be sure, you have to test or find a documentation of the onCallStateChanged method.

Comment: I'm testing on a NexusOne on 2.1, and OFFHOOK does NOT provide a phone number as a parameter, the string is simply empty (even though it is a field in the onCallStateChanged method). Can you confirm or deny this behavior on your phone? Here's some quick and dirty example code to use for testing: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html

Comment: I can confirm that this works on some devices and not others. For example, on a TMobile Fender the intent contains the phone number, but on a Sprint Hero it does not. Unfortunately there appears to be no way to tell (or even guess) which devices will behave as expected.