# how to tell if second incoming call is accepted or rejected in android?

Tags: android, phone-number

I am trying to figure out exact behavior of call especially in multiple calls.
Let's suppose I have three phones phone1, phone2, and phone3.
phone2 calls -> phone1 (in phone1, state changes from idle to ringing)
phone1 picks up the call from phone2 (in phone1, state changes from ringing to offhook)
phone3 calls -> phone1 (in phone1, state changes from offhook to ringing)

now I have three choices(**eventually two, accept or reject**).

- 1. reject the call from phone3
- 2-a. accept the call from phone3 and put call from phone2 in on-hold
- 2-b. accept the call from phone3 and hang up the call from phone2

All of these three actions have exact same state changes in phone1 as from ringing to offhook. So I can't figure out what really happens in phone1. Another approach that I can come up is **to figure out a way to retrieve phone number from the call that is currently on**. if I get this information then I can compare current phone number and previous phone number to figure out if phone3 call is accepted or rejected.

my problem seems to very similar to here: [Android: Detect currently active phone number during phone call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592086/android-detect-currently-active-phone-number-during-phone-call)
someone answered it but I have no idea how to make it work.

I have phone state, call log, and contact permission so far and I have broadcast receiver to see those state changes.

```
class CustomReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        CustomHandler.onStateChanged(context, intent)
    }
}
```

and checking each state changes in CustomHandler.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You've linked 10 year old answer which is no longer valid, you should implement https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService

Comment: Thanks for the link @Pawel, but can I still make it work using PhoneStateListener?